# Can not reach CloudFront files for 30 minutes from the first request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I started using CloudFront for serving some of our files with custom origin.

Everything is set up (also SSL), but the files are not accessible.

it works like this:

1. I make a request for a file
2. CF responses with a 403 error
3. in about 30 minutes is file accessible (without any errors)

It seems to me, that the first 30 minutes is cloudfront propagating the file to their servers, but is it supposed to work like this?

I just can not tell my users, sorry, some images will be accessible in 30 minutes, please, come later.

Did I set up anything incorrectly or it is supported to work like this?

**EDIT** Resolved

I used the same url for accessing files as well as for custom origin. The reason it was not working the first minutes was, that CF accessed self and it just did not have the file cached.

Comment: It sounds like you tried to access the file before it was actually available. CloudFront cached the fact that it wasn't available. You had to wait 30 minutes for the cache to expire.

Comment: What kind of files are these? Is your custom origin outside of AWS? If so where is it located geographically?

Comment: @MarkB thanks, your answer guided me to resolve the issue!